# Estimating probability distribution function of data stream

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, goodness-of-fit, descriptive-statistics

Although a similar question exists, I couldn't find my answer. I'm not a statistician hence please neglect if some terminologies aren't correct and let me know if I am interpreting something wrong.

We are aware about Goodness of fit tests like Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, Anderson-Darling test, etc. However, these tests assume that the data is available with us before we begin with the test and we can the distribution that best fits the data.

I am working on data streams i.e. data is continuously arriving and is not stored due to its huge volume. In such a case, how do we estimate the distribution of the data stream?

Since I cannot store the entire data stream, is it acceptable if I sample it (and store these samples) and find the distribution that best fits the sampled data? Can I use it to represent the distribution of the entire data stream? I assume there is no concept-drift in the data stream.

Comment: What are the consequences of having a bad fit?  For example, suppose you  kept the sum and sum of squares of the most current 1,000 observations and assumed a normal distribution.  Now I don't expect this to work for your data.  But are you comparing characteristics of different streams?  If the means and standard deviations are the same but the distributions differ, does that matter?  Those are the kind of questions I think you need to address before one can help you meet your ultimate objective.